# How to improve efficiency in filtering spark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, filter

I have a spark dataframe "df" that contains 16 million rows.

I would like to filter the dataframe using a variable x on one of the columns.

I have tried the below statements:

df = df.where(data.country == x)

df = df.filter(data.country == x)

Both methods are taking roughly 6 minutes to run. Is there anything I can do to improve the runtime of this operation? I am running this code in AWS glue.

Comment: You may try to partition the data on `country` before filtering (if `country` is very low relative to the number of records of the whole dataset)

Comment: AWS Glue compared to EMR will be slower , you can try to use EMR , which will provide you more configurable options in terms of infrastructure

Comment: Are you sure that this is the part of the code which is slow? Where are you reading the data from and do you write it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, first step is to verify this is the issue. Spark is lazy. Try doing df.cache.count, then df.where(data.country == x).count to see if it's actually the filter that's slow.

Comment: both `filter` and `where` are exactly same. [`where` is an alias for `filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-where)

Answer (score -1):

try caching it without calling above methods.